# Units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] $

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [infinitely many units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ for any $d\gt1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118315/infinitely-many-units-in-mathbbz-sqrtd-for-any-d1)

This is an exercise of algebraic number theory.

Prove that in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] \ $ , d square-free integer, $ d > 0 \ $, there are infinite many units.

Any hint ?

Comment: You really want to require that $d$ be positive, no?

Comment: Have you covered Pell's equation?

Comment: If I recall correctly this can be shown using the norm function?

Comment: @Dylan: Thanks, I've edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hint:  The equation $$y^2-dx^2=1$$ has infinitely many solutions.  See [Pell's equation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

Another hint: What do we know about the norm of a unit?  What happens if an element has norm $1$?  Recall that the norm is multiplicative.

Comment: The main point here is that it suffices to find *one* nontrivial unit, that is, a nontrivial solution of Pell's equation.