# Units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that $$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]^{\times} = \{\pm(2 + \sqrt{5})^k : k \in
>  \mathbb{Z}\}$$

The inclusion $\supseteq$ is fairly easy by concerning that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is a multiplicative group and the norm function. The inclusion which I have trouble with is $\subseteq$. In the solutions of my book we assume at the beginning, that if $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, then we can assume $x \geq 1$ since $\pm x,\pm x^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. I do not fully understand this. Furthermore, there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$(2 + \sqrt{5})^m \leq x < (2 + \sqrt{5})^{m + 1}$$ which I also do not fully understand. Any help or any suggestions for a different proof would be appreciated.

Comment: $x$ is in particular a real number. If $x<0$ consider $-x>0$. Now can assume $x>0$. If $0<x<1$, then consider $1/x>1$.

Comment: The powers of $2+\sqrt5$ form a strictly ascending chain of real numbers $\ge1$ (for $m=0$ you get $1$). Then your $x\ge 1$ must fall between two consecutive elements of this sequence since they split the interval $[1,\infty)$ into disjoint intervals.

Comment: There are many helpful answers for this on MSE, see for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124775/find-units-in-mathbbz-sqrtn) and the link to related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality , we can suppose $x$ is a unit and  $x\ge 1$.

> $2+\sqrt{5} $ is the smallest unit greater than 1.

Proof:

> Assume $x=a+b\sqrt{5}$ is a unit and $1< x=a+b\sqrt{5}<2+\sqrt{5}$.
>
> Firstly , we have $a^2-5b^2=\pm 1$.So we can get $-1< a-b\sqrt{5}< 1$.
>
> Thus $0<2a<3+\sqrt{5}$.
>
> If $a=1$, we can get $b=0$.A contradiction.
>
> If $a=2$, we can get $b=1$.A contradiction.

We complete the proof of the claim.

$\forall ~x\ge 1$, there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(2+\sqrt{5})^k\le x <(2+\sqrt{5})^{k+1}$.

So we have $1\le x(2+\sqrt{5})^{-k}<2+\sqrt{5}$.

Using the claim, we can get  $x=1$ or $x=(2+\sqrt{5})^k$.

Finally the units of  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is $\left\{ \pm ~(2+\sqrt{5})^k,~k\in \mathbb{Z} \right\} $.